# Adding element to 2d arraylist in java

Tags: java, arraylist

```
ArrayList<Integer> a =new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> j =new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

a.add(1);
a.add(2);
a.add(3);

for(int c=0; c<10; c++){
    j.add(a);
}
j.get(3).add(1);
System.out.println(j);
```

Does anyone know why this code adds 1 to every element of j as opposed to only the third element, and what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 11):

This is what happens when you add array list `a` to array list `j` 10 times.
[image: ![enter image description here]

This is what happens when you add `1` to array list `a`.

[image: ![enter image description here]

So basically all 10 indexes of ArrayList `j` points to a single ArrayList `a`. Hence, printing of value from any index of `j` will always gives you the same result.

---

To let each index point to a different array list:

[image]

Comment: Question if you wanted to add a value at the "element" 10x10 meaning the last entry in 'j' and entry 'a'.  `j.get(9).add(9, <my Int>);`

Answer (score 3):

You use the very same `ArrayList` `a` instance in every element of `j`.
You have to create a new instance of `ArrayList` for every element of `j` if you want them to be different.

Answer (score 2):

```
        for(int c=0; c<10; c++)
        {
            j.add(new ArrayList<>(a));
        }
```

In your code a is the pointer to the memory location where the ArrayList resides.

Answer (score -1):

Actually j.get(3) references the arrayList a as every j.get(c), that's why every cells of j pointing on a are changed. the next image shows how it works.[image: illustration]

Comment: You don't use square brackets for get